# Applying unknown member for different measure groups with many-to-many relationships

Tags: ssas, cube

I'm trying to apply a flag column from a data source that will use a yes or no lookup and will have many-to-many relationship with other measure groups. But I can't get the results to work properly.

This is the scenario. I have a cube with many measure groups. One of the data sources is a view and in this one I'm creating a calculated column with number "1" fixed, as it will ALWAYS have a yes answer for that question. Then I created a flag dimension with fixed data, like, "1" as id and "Yes" as description. After mapping the source to the dimension, they work fine as they are.

Thing is, I need to use this measure group with others that aren't using the same flag dimension. So I configured the unknown member properties to show "No" when the join brings null, and mapped the measure groups with the dimension with many-to-many. I was expecting that when processing the cube the new column would bring "no" as a result for the other measure groups, but  instead is bringing a blank column (not as expected) and it keeps bringing "yes" for the measure group that that has the flag column (as expected).
I need some pointers.

Comment: it's quite hard for now to understand why many-to-many is used here, could you please add an image with expected result? any fake image (or table) with this dimension on axis (or as a filter) + several measure groups measures.

Comment: @AlexPeshik Thanks for the attention. I can't post an imagem right now, but I'll try later. As for the many-to-many: it's a cube that was formerly single, and now it must be included in a bigger one.
This bigger one already has 8 measure groups, not all regularly linked between themselves. This little new one is being included as a new measure group since the client is trying to "merge" visions alltogether. I know it isn't the best way, but is how the client want. So we have to use a lot of many-to-many relationships so the client can see through different measure groups in a single shot.